# router.replace() method results in slow navigation in expo router when navigating from a 'modal' presented screen to a regular screen

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I have the following folder architecture using expo router v2 and expo sdk 49
[folder architecture for expo router v2 navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOyKf.png)

I am transitioning from several modal presented screens to a regular screen using router.replace() because the router.push() changes the screen on the back but leaves the modal screen on top for some reason.

I have found that there is a lag when I do this that does not happen when I use a back or swipe down to dismiss the modal.

here is a code snippet that I use to produce this problem:

```
const Settings = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Settings</Text>
      <Button
        title="go to user profile"
        onPress={() => router.replace('/(tabs)/(user-profile)/UserProfile')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Settings;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

I tried using router.push() but that results in the screen I insert into the push method being loaded in the back but the modal screen from which I call the method stays on top.